# recipentList camel routeloo

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I am new to camel, and I have a camel route which I need to set up using a property file with header value to pass to the endpoint and write the response to a file.

I am hoping that there is a way to set the timer such that each time the route runs it would pass in the next {{pid}} in the property file to the url for the http request, and not erase the previous output file, but add the response on top of it. So far the route seems to be just passing the last pid listed in property file and only runs once. How can I set the route to run as many times as the items in the property file and have each response log to a same file? any help is appreciated.

```
public static void main(final String[] args)  {
    try {

    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
    camelContext.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));      
    camelContext.getProperties().put(Exchange.LOG_DEBUG_BODY_STREAMS, "true");
    PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();

    //added property placeholder file
    pc.setLocation("file:C:/Users/xuzc/Desktop/camel inbox/properties.txt");
    camelContext.addComponent("properties", pc);
    pc.setPropertyPrefix("{{pid}}");

    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception{

               from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=100") 
                .id("get xml")
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/xml")) 
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING, constant("UTF-8")) 
                .to("log:httpbefore.SYSTEM.COM?level=DEBUG&ShowHeaders=true&ShowBody=true")

                //.loop(3)

                .to("http://appurl/objects/{{pid}}/datastreams/MASTER?validateChecksum=true&format=xml")


                .setBody(xpath("//dsChecksumValid=@value").stringResult()) //only output the xpath specified to string
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .to("file:target/reports?fileName=checksum{$id}"); //output xml result to file


        }
    });


    camelContext.start();

    camelContext.stop();

} 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct use of properties. Properties are meant to be **configuration values** for routes rather than **input data**.
You can save your *pid* values in a text file and let Camel process it. For example:
this is the content of `inputfile.txt`

> URL-A
>   URL-B
>   URL-C

put it in a folder to start the following Camel route:

```
from("file://inputDirectory") 
    .id("get xml")
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/xml")) 
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING, constant("UTF-8")) 
    .to("log:httpbefore.SYSTEM.COM?level=DEBUG&ShowHeaders=true&ShowBody=true")
    .split(body(String.class).tokenize("\n"))  // repeat the following for each row
        .recipientList(simple("http://appurl/objects/${body}/datastreams/MASTER?validateChecksum=true&format=xml"))
        .setBody(xpath("//dsChecksumValid=@value").stringResult()) //only output the xpath specified to string
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("file:target/reports?fileName=checksum-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}");
```

The splitter will call the rest of the route once for every line in the input file, so will call urls:

> http://appurl/objects/URL-A/datastreams/MASTER...
>   http://appurl/objects/URL-B/datastreams/MASTER...
>   http://appurl/objects/URL-C/datastreams/MASTER...

and each response will be saved to its own file. You can change the `fileName` value to match any property or Exchange header you like.
See [Splitter pattern](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) and [File component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) for more details.

**edit**: I realized you would like to save all responses in the same file, change the last line to

```
.to("file:target/reports?fileName=checksum-${id}&fileExist=Append");
```

**edit2**: use `recipientList()` instead of `to()`
[RecipientList](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html) sends the exchange to an endpoint dynamically, using [simple language](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) to prepare the URI. I forgot `to()` does not support dynamic URIs, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Rugna and point out the spliter method, it make sense. However, when I tried to use the 'propertyfile.txt' as consumer my route I couldn't get an http response from the route, whereas when I had it as a timer consumer I was able to see the content of the response and write it to the file. I also see a defaultErrorHandler on the log, Any ideas?

Comment: here's part of the log:
2016-11-16 12:13:23 DEBUG ProducerCache:423 - Adding to producer cache with key: Endpoint[http://appurl:8080/objects/$%7Bbody%7D/datastreams/MASTER?format=xml] for producer: Producer[http://appurl:8080/objects/$%7Bbody%7D/datastreams/MASTER?format=xml]
2016-11-16 12:13:23 DEBUG DefaultErrorHandler:1278 - Redelivery enabled: false on error handler: DefaultErrorHandler[Instrumentation:to[sendTo(Endpoint[http://appurl:8080/objects/$%7Bbody%7D/datastreams/MASTER?format=xml])]]

Comment: @Calvin I corrected the code (didn't test it though). My fault, I forgot to() does not support dynamic URIs

Comment: @Rugna  thanks again for the edit. I did try using recipient list before and I tried your code as well but still no luck, but from console logs says there's I'm suspecting that that there's something with the parsing? can you show me how to use the spliter in the Exchange component like in line 4 and 5? thanks!

Comment: @Calvin have a look at this working example https://github.com/darugnaa/apache-camel-examples/tree/master/camel-standalone-http

Comment: @Rugna great example! I was thinking going down that path and write a custom processor but didn't get very far. Can you help me understand why you had two old and new exchange messages? thanks!

Comment: @Calvin read this http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html  The aggregator uses 'old' exchange to build the result of processing each single element in the split, which is passed in the 'new' exchange.